# Fetch source address and port number of packet - Scapy script

Tags: networking, python-2.7, tcp, scapy

I am doing a sniffing of the network and trying to get ip address and port number on every tcp packet.

I used scapy with python and could successfully sniff packets and in a callback function could even print the packet summary. But I would want to do more, like fetching only the IP address of the source and its port number. How can i accomplish it? Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python
from scapy.all.import.*
def print_summary(pkt):
    packet = pkt.summary()
    print packet
sniff(filter="tcp",prn=packet_summary)
```

Please suggest a method to print only the source IP address of every packet.

Thanks.

Comment: All I had to do was pkt[IP].src to fetch the IP address of the source. It was simple and yet took a lot of time of mine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not very difficult. Try the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *
def print_summary(pkt):
    if IP in pkt:
        ip_src=pkt[IP].src
        ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
    if TCP in pkt:
        tcp_sport=pkt[TCP].sport
        tcp_dport=pkt[TCP].dport

        print " IP src " + str(ip_src) + " TCP sport " + str(tcp_sport) 
        print " IP dst " + str(ip_dst) + " TCP dport " + str(tcp_dport)

    # you can filter with something like that
    if ( ( pkt[IP].src == "192.168.0.1") or ( pkt[IP].dst == "192.168.0.1") ):
        print("!")

sniff(filter="ip",prn=print_summary)
# or it possible to filter with filter parameter...!
sniff(filter="ip and host 192.168.0.1",prn=print_summary)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I'm using Scapy 2.3 and I had to quote those keys in `if IP in pkt` and `if TCP in pkt`,  same when accessing their values.

Comment: Typo in the first line of the script. Should be: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: If i want to count duplicates(ports) from pkt[TCP].sport. How to do that?

Comment: It was printing all ports with repetition. But i want to print without duplication/repeatition ports, mean while i want to count how may times that port was repeated.

Answer (score 4):

User2871462 has a terrific answer, I would comment on it but I don't have the required amount of reputation. :) The only thing I would add is that depending on the use case you may want to add the store=0 flag to the sniff call so you're not storing the packets. From the scapy docstring "store: wether to store sniffed packets or discard them".

```
sniff(filter="ip",prn=print_summary, store=0)
```