# I need to print the port I got a packet from

Tags: python, scapy

I have this code:

```
from scapy.all import *

def filter_IP(packet):
    return (UDP in packet and packet[IP].src=='127.0.0.1')

letter = sniff(count=1,lfilter==filter_IP)
for l in letter:
    print l.show()
```

This prints the whole packet with all of it detail and I need to print just the port.

Comment: I think you mean "packet", not "package".

Comment: By "port" do you mean the UDP port number (for example, 53 for DNS packets)? Or do you mean the Ethernet interface on which the packet arrived?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311673/fetch-source-address-and-port-number-of-packet-scapy-script)

I hope my response will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for l in letter:
    print l[UDP].sport, l[UDP].dport
```